# Как правильно cделать transparent UINavigator bar Image?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, navigationbar

Добрый вечер! подскажите как сделать при детальном открытие сцены прозрачный навигатор бар? Во ViewController я поместил TableviewCell, после чего беру вставляю view и сверху накладываю картинку, после чего загоняю за до упора под навигатор бар.Почему то не действует метод.Картинку я закреплял все точки влево, вправо, вверх, вниз.Когда фиксацию не делаю метод работает.Видел где то почему то картинку до навигатор бара фиксируют и все срабатывает.Подскажите в чем допускается ошибка у меня.Может че то не допонял.Очень буду благодарен.Если можно подробную ссылку.
Вот код который использую

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавте код ниже в `AppDelegate` в метод `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool`

Тут `UIImage(color: UIColor(red: 136.0/255.0, green: 136.0/255.0, blue: 136.0/255.0, alpha: 0.8)` можете подобрать цвет который вам по душе.

Если вы пропишите это в `AppDelegate`, то настройки будут во всем проекте. Если это вам не подходит то пропишите это в классе. Вместо `UINavigationBar.appearance()` подставьте `self.navigationController?.navigationBar`

```
let imagebar : UIImage = UIImage(color: UIColor(red: 136.0/255.0, green: 136.0/255.0, blue: 136.0/255.0, alpha: 0.8), size: CGSize(width: bounds.size.width, height: 84))!
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(imagebar, for: .default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
```

Comment: у меня это в классе и есть .